# Use pthread mutex with different thread framework

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am writing a joystick library in C and I would like to make it thread safe. Is it okay to use pthread mutexes? Will they work even when the application that uses my library uses, for example, ACE as a thread framework (not sure if ACE does not just extends pthread, but let's assume it does not)?

Same goes for Windows: Can I use Windows' `CriticalSection` in combination with pthread in mingw+gcc? Or is threading something the OS must do so that the native implementation is always used (pthread on Linux and `CriticalSection` on Windows)?

Comment: Ultimately, mutex functionality must be provided by the OS kernel at a low level. Mingw+gcc must use Window's native locking to implement pthread's mutexes. I'd be inclined to think this could work.

Comment: @EzequielMuns Mutex isn't required to be provided by the OS. Spin locks occur entirely at the user level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads can operate at the *user level* and therefore there is no guarantee that the OS will schedule all concurrency. With that said, you should always seek to make your library thread-safe without requiring a specific locking mechanism on your users.

For example, you can make all functions "pure" or reentrant. You can also offer a version that is explicitly **not** thread-safe and an alternative version that requires a specific library, like pthread. In the most extreme case you can offer lock-free synchronization.